# Question about relationship between $\ell^ p$ spaces and Fourier coefficients.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis

let $f\in L^2(\mathbb{T})$, and let $f(x)=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}B_nsin(nx)$ be the associated Fourier sine series (which of course is an orthonormal basis for for $L^2(\mathbb{T})$).

Consider a sequence $a_n \in \ell^2({\mathbb{Z}})$ where all terms are zero except for multiples of $3$. Is it true that there exists a unique $f\in L^2(\mathbb{T})$, up to a set of measure zero, that has the fourier coefficients $B_n=a_n$? Would this mean that $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$ contains all possible combinations of Fourier coefficients (at least for functions in $L^2(\mathbb{T})$)?

I think it is true because of course, such an $a_n$ exists as an appropriate linear combination of basis elements in $\ell^2({\mathbb{Z}})$. Also, you can map these to an appropriate linear combination of basis elements in $L^2(\mathbb{T})$, so such a function with those fourier coefficients must exist.

I am unsure how to show the following analogous result for $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})\cap \ell^p(\mathbb{Z})$, $p\geq5$. Here is the precise statement.

let $a_n\in \ell^2(\mathbb{Z})\cap \ell^p(\mathbb{Z})$, $p\geq5$, where $a_n$ are the Fourier coefficients for the Fourier series $f(x)=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}B_nsin(nx)$, 
where $f\in L^2(\mathbb{T})\cap L^p(\mathbb{T}), p\geq 5$.

Is it still true that there exists a sequence $a_n\in \ell^2(\mathbb{Z})\cap \ell^p(\mathbb{Z})$, $p\geq5$ which is zero except for multiples of $3$, prime numbers or any other possible sequence, where $a_n$ corresponds exactly to the Fourier coefficients $B_n$ for $f\in L^2(\mathbb{T})\cap L^p(\mathbb{T}), p\geq 5$. How would I prove this?

Comment: for $p > 2 $ : $l^2(\mathbb{Z}) \subset l^p(\mathbb{Z})$ so $l^2(\mathbb{Z}) \cap l^p(\mathbb{Z}) = l^2(\mathbb{Z})$. Conversely $L^p(\mathbb{T}) \subset L^2(\mathbb{T}) $ so $L^2(\mathbb{T})\cap L^p(\mathbb{T}) = L^p(\mathbb{T})$

Comment: Could you please explain how you get $l^2(\mathbb Z) \subset l^p (\mathbb Z)$? Maybe write an answer? I would love to know how to prove this.

Comment: I can see how $L^p(\mathbb{T})\cap L^2(\mathbb{T})$. By Carleson-Hunt theorem, every Fourier series converges pointwise almost everywhere to an $f\in L^p(\mathbb{T})$, so this means every function in $L^p(\mathbb{T})$ can be expressed as an infinite linear combination of some basis in $L^2$, but of course, not every $L^p$ function is $L^2$. However, I want to know what conditions we can impose on the Fourier coefficients $B_n$ so that $f$ is both in $L^2$ and $L^p$ for $p\geq 5$. That is why I thought to study the space $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})\cap \ell^p(\mathbb{Z})$.

Answer (score 2):

I only know the answer to the first part of your question, I'm afraid. Hopefully an expert will answer the rest.

It's certainly true that if $a_n \in \mathcal l^2(\mathbb Z)$, then $\sum_{n\in \mathbb N} a_n e^{2\pi inx}$ defines a valid element in $L^2(\mathbb T)$, and vice versa.

[I'm going to use complex exponentials as my basis for $L^2(\mathbb T)$ but I don't think it particularly matters if you use sines instead...]

Here is the argument: If $a_n \in \mathcal l^2(\mathbb Z)$, then $$\sum_{n\in \mathbb N} |a_n |^2 < \infty,$$so the sequence of partial sums, $$ n \mapsto \sum_{m = 1}^n |a_m|^2, $$is a Cauchy sequence.

But for any $n > n'$, the orthogonality of $e^{2\pi imx}$ implies that
$$ || \sum_{m=1}^{n} a_me^{2\pi imx} - \sum_{m=1}^{n'}a_me^{2\pi imx} ||^2 \leq \sum_{m=1}^{n} |a_m |^2 - \sum_{m=1}^{n'} |a_m |^2. $$
So the sequence $$n \mapsto \sum_{m=1}^{n} a_me^{2\pi imx} $$ is a Cauchy sequence in $L^2(\mathbb T)$.

Hence the limit $$ \sum_{m=1}^\infty a_m e^{2\pi i mx} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{m=1}^{n} a_me^{2\pi imx} $$ exists in $L^2(\mathbb T)$ by completeness.

The reverse argument is identical.

I can't say anything useful about the $l^2(\mathbb Z) \cap l^p (\mathbb Z)$ conjecture, I'm afraid. Of course, the isomorphism of vector spaces $$\{ a_n \} \mapsto \sum_{n} a_n e^{2\pi i n x}$$ does not map the $l^p(\mathbb Z)$ norm to the $L^p(\mathbb T^2)$ norm unless $p = 2$, which is why it's tricky.